# Avoiding duplicates in Elasticsearch, discriminating over different IDs?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm fairly new to Elasticsearch, I have been trying to come with the idea of merging data which belongs to the same entity, but not always having the same columns.

For example, let's say I'm getting cars from database1 and database2.

In database1 I have the plate, the weight and the color, and for example VIN number
and in database2 I have the color, the date of creation and, the VIN number again
and now in database3, I might for example have, color, date of creation and plate.

If I were to add a car A from database1, and then the same car A from database 3, ID (plate) would collide, but if I was to do with database2, it wouldn't collide and would create 2 different documents of the same instance.

I'd like to know if there's a way maybe use "multiple optional IDs", being able to use 1, both of them, or the other, depending on the data I add each time, as different databases would have different fields.

Thanks.

Comment: generally the approach here would be to read the data from each of the 3 databases and then insert a single, merged document, using something like the VIN as the identifier (or `_id` in Elasticsearch)

Comment: @MarkWalkom Hi Mark, thanks for the answer,  so, in order to avoid duplicates, I should, manually, give my program some logic like (if x or y or z are in the database already, treat it  as a duplicate and just update/add new info, instead of creating a new one). 

I guess that would work, but I guess it will heaviliy increase the insertion times, cause it should have to do n queries, and then realize the insertion, maybe I could make it concurrent, yeah..